# getting the value from the id and pass it to a function

Tags: javascript, html

Does any one know where am I making my mistake ?

```js
function functionTest(name) {
  var Name = name;
  alert(Name);

}
```

```html
<h3 id="name" value="testingName"><a href="#"> test </a></h3>
<button onclick="functionTest(document.getElementById('name').value)"></button>
```

The output is  undefined

Comment: `<h3>` elements don't *have* a "value".  Did you mean to use a `data-*` attribute instead?  Something else?

Comment: `h3` don't have `value`. Try using `innerHTML` instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<h3>` elements don't *have* a `value` attribute.  But you can use `data-*` attributes instead.  Something like this:

```
<h3 id="name" data-value="testingName">
```

Then you'd access it from the `dataset` property:

```
document.getElementById('name').dataset.value
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/d3v9fpfe/), using your original code

```js
function functionTest(name) {
  var Name = name;
  alert(Name);
}
```

```html
<h3 id="name" data-value="testingName"><a href="#"> test </a></h3>
<button onclick="functionTest(document.getElementById('name').dataset.value)"></button>
```

Comment: Is dataset cross-os/browser? What is it's benefits vs `getAttribute('data-value')`? I have nothing against it, any beneficial change is welcome.

Comment: @voldomazta: I'm not certain, to be honest.  That's just what MDN shows as the way to access data attributes.  Worth testing, I suppose.

Comment: @David Thanks for your exclusive explanation . Now it makes more sense XD

Answer (score 2):

You have a bunch of semantic issues with your code. For starters, the `value` attribute is usually only intended for `<input>` tags.

If you really want to make the code work without modifying the HTML code, then `document.getElementById('name').getAttribute('value')` will suffice, but that is adding one mistake after another.

What I would do is something like:

```
<h3 id="name" data-value="testingName"><a href="#"> test </a></h3>
<button onclick="functionTest(document.getElementById('name').getAttribute("data-value"))"></button>
```

This is semantically correct because headers (or any tag for that matter) can have attributes that start with `data-`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `getAttribute` on the element here is the corrected code

```js
function functionTest(name) {
  var Name = name;
  alert(Name);

}
```

```html
<h3 id="name" value="testingName"><a href="#"> test </a></h3>
<button onclick="functionTest(document.getElementById('name').getAttribute('value'))"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`H3` dont have value attribute.It have `innerHTML` attribute.

`value` on it considered as custom user defined attribute.You can get it using `getAttribute`

If you want to get `innerHTML`,then you should use like this

```
function functionTest(){
        var Name = name ;
        console.log(document.getElementById('name').innerHTML);
      console.log(document.getElementById('name').getAttribute('value'))

      }
```

Comment: Because it's going to an alert don't use innerHTML on an HTML element that can contain other elements. Use textContent.

Comment: @zfrisch agree.But SO post doesn't put any specific requirement.Thanks for addition

Answer (score -2):

Use

```
<button onclick="functionTest(document.getElementById('name').getAttribute("value"))"></button>
```